# Computing descriptives statistics for sites and locations based on literature search with sites having varying numbers of time points

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, mean, standard-error

I've collected a data set from the literature. These data are largely binomial: they are clutch sizes of a bird that lays only 1 or 2 eggs in most areas, and in some areas will lay 3. However the only information I have compiled are means, standard errors and sample sizes (# nests) from various sites. Some sites have multiple values reported from them (from different years), and I have split the sites into 3 categories based on location (A, B and C).

I want to do 2 things that are essentially the same:

1. Produce one value (± SE or SD) for each site (so a site mean)
2. Produce a location mean ± SE or SD (so an average of all the sites within a given location category).

Is it possible to do this relatively simply while keeping the information contained with the reported standard errors from each site?

Currently, I've taken a mean of the means of each site within a location category, and just calculated the SE from the mean of means, but that's losing all the reported variation from each site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use weighted means. Given a set of $n$ experiments that had mean and standard error $(x_i,\sigma_i)$ we can calculate the overall mean and standard error $(x,\sigma)$ is calculated as follows:

$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{(\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{\sigma_i^2})}$

and

$x = \sigma^2 (\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{x_i}{\sigma_i^2})$

This is the maximum likelihood estimator of the combined mean under the assumption that the sub-experiments are independent and normally distributed with the same mean. This is often a valid assumption (since most distributions tend towards normal by central-limit theorem), and for instance, this is the most popular way to quickly combine results of experiments measuring the same quantity in fields like physics.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I have a question about it: you say we assume the "sub-experiments are independent and normally distributed with the same mean". My data are not normally distributed...they're essentially binomial (clutch size of a bird that lays only 1 or 2 eggs in most locations, and very occasionally 3 eggs in some areas). It didn't occur to me to include that - apologies for that. Any chance I can still use this method?